# Handling of subselects in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In the following example we want to find duplicates with different ids

```
-- table msg
create table msg(
    id int primary key,
    msg varchar(10));

insert into msg
    values (1, 'single'),
           (2, 'twice'),
           (3, 'twice'),
           (4, 'threefold'),
           (5, 'threefold'),
           (6, 'threefold');

select * from msg;
```

Counting the number of identical messages with different ids

First example:

```
select id, msg, (select count(*) from msg m1 where m1.msg = msg) as cnt 
    from msg;
```

=> wrong result since "msg" in subselect is identified with "m1.msg", not "msg.msg"

Second example:

```
select id, msg, (select count(*) from msg m1 where msg.msg = m1.msg) as cnt 
    from msg;
```

=> correct result

Third example (may be easier to understand):

```
select m1.id, m1.msg, (select count(*) from msg m2 where m1.msg = m2.msg) as cnt 
    from msg m1;
```

=> correct result

Question: 
Is the behaviour of the first example conform with the SQL standard?

Comment: Yes, that's how the SQL standard defines visibility of the identifiers

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me a hint where in the standard I can find this specification? Is "Foundation 6.6. <identifier chain>" the right place to look for?

Answer (score 0):

Always We should user table alias and refer the same with column name. Otherwise database will assume anyway so we wont get desired result.

referring table alias also solve some performance problem. Assume you have joined n tables and refer tables columns in select clause and where clause. When you execute the query, system will parse the query during that parsing it will check column availability in the respective tables. If you are not use alias name then it has to check all the table and find which table have that column. It may take time. To avoid that we have to refer the table alias name in respective columns. Also to avoid column ambiguously defined error

In subquery we always refer the table alias with the column